# Retrieve access_token from authorization part of website without web request

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

My website is made up of multiple parts (API, IdSrv, MVC, etc.).

The IdSvr site handles authorization and issues access and id tokens and handles user management.
The API site stores information regarding the user, which is not related to his identity (thus it isn't stored on the IdSvr site).

The IdSvr site displays user information which is pulled from the API (and other sites). For that I need to authorize the user with the API via access token. To retrieve that access token the IdSvr site would need to make a http request against the IdSrv site, to then call the API site with the token to get the actual data.
This seems odd to me and I'm looking for a way to get an access token without the need for the IdSvr site to make a request against itself.

I already tried `var accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");` as it was shown in the Identity Server examples, however this returns an empty access token.

The logs don't tell much, except:

> [15:22:28 Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler
>   AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was successfully authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

OK, updated answer following clarification provided in the comments.

I think the reason you are finding this tricky is that you are asking your ID server to return details that are not related to authentication.  From your client, it seems like this should be two calls:

1. Authorise against the ID server.
2. Using that access token, request user details (specific to the site that I am trying to access) from that site, rather than the ID server.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question: The IdSvr site issues the access_tokens. However since that site also handles user management it sometimes needs to call the api site to retrieve some additional user info. To request the api resources I need to call the API (which I'm already doing), but for that I need an access token. To retrieve that, the IdSrv site would need to make a http request against the IdSrv site, which seems very odd. I'll update the qording on the original question.

Comment: @Ruhrpottpatriot - is that not circular?  Should the identity server not stand alone, with direct access to the user information?

Comment: No. The user information isn't related to the IdSvr site at all and hasn't to do anything with authorization. E.g. in a game you have a number of characters which are all stored inside the API site database. The IdSvr site then only displays the number of characters). However since characters are personal they need to be behind auth. I'm aware that I need to make a IdSvr -> API request. And I'm currently doing that, but I want to avoid the IdSvr -> IdSvr request.

Comment: 1. Thanks for the updated response. 2. What if the client is the IDSvr itself?

Comment: I think that's my point - the ID server should never be this client.